# Unable to set cookies from backend to frontend when deploying website

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, axios, dns

I'm using Nodejs for my server and Reactjs for my client. In my client, I use axios to perform post/get requests to the server.
During development, everything is working perfectly fine, data is fetched and cookies are set properly. However, when I deploy my server and client to Heroku and Netlify respectively, the cookies are suddenly not set.

Here is my server code:

```
dotenv.config()
const server = express();
server.use(cors({origin: "https://frontendname.com", credentials: true}));

server.use(express.json());
server.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))
server.use(cookieParser())
server.use("/", fetchData)

server.listen(process.env.PORT, ()=>console.log(`Server listening on PORT ${process.env.PORT}`))
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}).then( () => {
    console.log("connected to mongoose")
    

}).catch((error) => console.log(error.message))
```

My server API code

```
res.status(201)       .cookie("accessToken", accessToken, {domain:"frontendwebsite.com", httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'strict', path: '/', expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 1000 * 4)})                          .cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, {domain:"frontendwebsite.com", httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'strict', path: '/', expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 1000 * 96)})                          .json({message: "login verified", username: req.body.username})                 .send()
```

My client API code:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
export const loginAuth = async (credentials) => { 
    return await axios.post("https://backendname.herokuapp.com/loginAuth", credentials).then((res) => {
        
        return res
    })
}
```

I have a strong feeling its due to the domain name that is not correct in the "res.cookie". Since in my development when I'm using localhost for both server and client, it works. My client is hosted on Netlify and server is hosted on Heroku. My client has a custom domain name I got from GoDaddy. I used Netlify DNS on that domain name. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you inspect the response coming back from your server (with browser Dev Tools)? Is there any Set-Cookie header / value returning, or is it completely missing?

My guess is the cookie header is there, and being set, but with `sameSite` set to `strict` it won't send it to your backend / API. So I think you are right about the domain being incorrect, in `res.cookie`, you could try that with `backendname.herokuapp.com`. Since really you want the cookie to be transmitting to / from your backend, especially as it is `httpOnly`, it will never be used by your frontend / client.

Comment: Hi, firstly, thanks for the reply. I have since tried several changes but to no avail. 

I do receive the Set-Cookie header with all options like httponly, sameSite and expiry time intact. However I still do not see the cookie in the cookies tab. Also played around with the domain name, varying with a https, http and no prefix at all, as well as leaving the trailing slash at the end of the domain. Changing sameSite to none, domain to my backend address didn't work as well. 

Any ideas?

Comment: Since the Set-Cookie header is there, that means the problem is entirely client-side. I'd recommend going to Dev Tools -> Console in Chrome, and clicking the "Issues" button, then checking "Include third-party cookie issues".  Once you reload, should show any errors that occurred when the browser is trying to set the cookie.

Comment: I think I'm close. I ran it on Firefox and an error in the console says that the cookies would soon be rejected due to the lack of "secure" options. I set "secure" to be true , the error is fixed, but it still didn't work. 

One thing notable is that the when I set the domain to my frontend address or backend address, there would be an error saying "the cookie has been rejected for invalid domain". When I remove the domain option completely, the error disappears. However the cookie still doesn't appear.

Comment: I think that is the right track, you shouldn't need the `domain` set, as by default it will be the domain that you set it from (backend). Can you also remove the `path` and see what happens? When you say the cookie doesn't appear, are you look at subsequent requests (`Cookie` header) in network tab? I think the next thing you are running into is `SameSite` being set to `strict` as your frontend / backend are different domains. However, that should be showing up in error console after you send a request. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

Comment: The sameSite was set to 'none' previously along with the addition of secure set to true. In the network tab, I still see Set-Cookie header in the response, just that Chrome DevTools, under Application, cookies remain empty.

Comment: Viewing a later request made to the backend server (after the cookie should have been set) is there no `Cookie` header + value being passed either? Just thinking DevTools may not be showing the cookie for when on the "Frontend" domain, if it is http only, and set for backend. Even though it is being set / sent properly for backend.

Comment: Yeah, you were right from the start. Cookies are being set and actually present in frontend. Just not displaying in DevTools. When I send `document.cookie` to the backend, all the cookies are showing. I tried setting `httpOnly = false` but still didn't show up. But at least cookies are set in the frontend which is good news to me.